# An open problem about simple Noetherian rings

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, open-problems

The following is a well-known open problem in ring theory (see, for instance, Goodearl, Warfield, 'An introduction to noncommutative Noetherian rings, Appendix, Problem 19)

**Question:** Let $R$ be a left Noetherian simple ring. Can every left ideal be generated by two elements?

The history of this problem goes back to the seminal work of Stafford 'Module structure of the Weyl algebra'. In this paper, Stafford showed, among other things, that $k$ being a field of zero characteristic, every left ideal for the Weyl algebras $A_n(k)$ can be generated by two elements.

In the same paper, he stated as problem to find large classes of algebras for which his results on the Weyl algebras also hold; in particular, the two-generation property of left ideals.

A lot of research has been done on this topic. There are some natural generalizations of Stafford's result for algebras that are similar to the Weyl algebra: the two-generation property of left ideals holds for $k(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\langle \partial_1, \ldots, \partial_n \rangle$, and the subalgebra of $End_k k((x_1,\ldots,x_n))$ generated by $k((x_1,\ldots,x_n))$ and the usual partial derivatives $\partial_1, \ldots, \partial_n$.

Bavula showed that the two-generation property for left ideals holds for many generalized Weyl algebras - for example, it holds for the quantum torus $k_q[x^\pm,y^\pm]$, when $q$ is not a root of unity.

A natural question, raised in 1980 by Björk, is if we have the two-generation property for left ideals for rings of differential operators on smooth affine varieties. Coutinho and Holland worked on this problem, and showed that every left ideal for such rings can be generated by *three* elements - and Björk's question is still open. If we consider the Weyl algebra $A_n(D)$ over a division ring $D$ of zero characteristic, we have a similar result, obtained by Byun: every left ideal can be generated by three elements.

All of the above are particular cases of rings. The only general result I know, also due to Stafford, is the following: let $R$ be a simple left Noetherian ring with Krull dimension $d$. Then every left ideal can be generated by $d+1$ elements.

I am curious for what reasons there are to believe or not that every left ideal for a simple left Noetherian ring can be generated by two elements. Sure, the results I described above count as positive evidence to believe this fact. However, in my opinion, all those rings above are rather similar in nature: all of them are some natural generalization of the Weyl algebra.

So, besides the above discussed positive results and lack of counter-examples, are there other  reasons to believe in a positive solution to this open problem?